# Lowering operator for spherical harmonics

Tags: differential-equations, operators

I need to be able to generate all of the $ l=2 $ spherical harmonics using the lowering operator. The specific question is listed below. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shco1.jpg)

[image]

Comment: And how is this to the Wolfram Mathematica, the software to which this Q&A site is dedicated?

Comment: You might have better luck on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). Unless you specifically want to do this using Mathematica.

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: Belongs to physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

```
Y[l_, m_] := 
 Y[l, m] = Nest[Simplify[Exp[-I*ϕ] (-D[#, θ] + 
        I*Cot[θ]*D[#, ϕ])] &, Sin[θ]^l*Exp[I*l*ϕ], l - m]

(table1 = Table[Y[l, m], {l, 0, 2}, {m, 0, l}]) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Or

```
(table2 = table1 // TrigReduce) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:** As suggested by Alex Trounev, compare with the built-in [`SphericalHarmonicY`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalHarmonicY.html)

```
Table[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ], {l, 0, 2}, {m, 0, l}] // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** For clarity, look at the ratio of the two functions

```
Table[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ]/Y[l, m], {l, 0, 5}, {m, 0, l}] // 
  Simplify // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Bob can you add for comparison `Table[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {l, 0, 2}, {m, 0,  l}] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &`